# How to save data of tableviewCell with different category in Pickerview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a tableview which is filled with fruit, vegetable ,Meat. I am having problem at this point when I change category using UIPickerView my previous data which is saved in array gets deleted.

I don't know how to handle this problem. How will I save my previous category data and also when user change category?

Below is some of my code which I am working on.

**CellForRowAt**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "adddiseasefoodcell", for: indexPath) as! AddDiseaseTableViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)
    cell.foodname.text = foodname[indexPath.row]
    cell.foodimg.image = imagereturn(urrl: foodimage[indexPath.row])
    cell.unitlbl.text = foodunit[indexPath.row]
    cell.callbl.text = foodcal[indexPath.row]
    cell.switchFood.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.switchFood.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    print(check[indexPath.row]!)
   // check[indexPath.row] = false
    if check[indexPath.row]!
    {
        cell.switchFood.isOn = true
    }
    else
    {
        cell.switchFood.isOn = false
    }

    cell.switchFood.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(Sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

**SaveButtonCode**

```
 func buttonClicked(Sender:UIButton)
    {

        print(Sender.tag)
        let index = NSIndexPath(row: Sender.tag,section:0)
        let cell = foodnametableview.cellForRow(at:index as IndexPath) as! AddDiseaseTableViewCell


        if check[Sender.tag]!
        {
      //  cell.switchFood.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           cell.switchFood.isOn = false
            check[Sender.tag] = false
        }
        else
        {
        //    cell.switchFood.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.switchFood.isOn = true
            check[Sender.tag] = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you use different arrays for different categories and load table with  the selected category array?

Comment: @Shabirjan how? correct me if i am wrong your are saying if 4 categories are in pickerview then i have to create 4 different arrays?

Comment: Yes if you dont want to delete the old data of the array.

Comment: imagine i have save data in selectedarray. i have a problem after selecting data when tableview is populated when i change category previously save data in selectedarray gets deleted. @Shabirjan

Comment: thats why i asked you used different arrays for different categories, in that way you wont lost the save data

Comment: give me any example please? @Shabirjan

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different Arrays for each of your Category. And than you have to do it like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if selectedCategory == .meat {
         return meatArray.count
       }
       // same for other Catgories
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       //Create cell and other configurations
       if selectedCategory == .meat {
          let selectedFood = meatArray(indexPath.row)
          //use selectedFood object to get values and use it in the cell
       }

        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Now i am having problem on that stage where i checked some item from **first category** and change my category to **second category** and selected some other things, after that when i change back to **first category** the selected item that i selected first before changing category are no more selected that is the issue now?

Comment: For that you need to add a property in your custom cell that will remember the state of the item if it is selected or not. and you will need to store the property as well and in the cellforrowatindespath you need to check if item is selected or not.

Comment: i have a check[int:bool] dictionary which is filled with false where i am counting row for tableview. and i am replacing true when item is selected but when i change category this dictionary is refilled with false so i am stuck there. i hope you are getting my point.

Comment: than i would suggest to create 4 different check dictionary  for each category than you wont lost the checked item.

Comment: i am unable to handle that array whenever i came back after changing category all selected items are gone

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to implement this is to add element in array with categories and retrieve array data with its index accordingly. For this you have to save data in dictionary with category as key and elements as value.

Comment: that will be good but i am having problem on that stage where i checked some item from **first category** and change my category to **second category** and selected some other things, after that when i change back to **first category** the selected item that i selected first before changing category are no more selected that is the issue now?